# Perl func for printing array

Tags: arrays, perl

Is there a default function perl5 that does approximately this:

```
map {print $array[$_]} qw/1 5 7/; # i don't care about 2, 3, 4, 6 and whatever next indexes
```

One function instead of three?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Or:

```
print @array[1,5,7];
```

One function, as you required.

This is called an array slice, you can learn more about it from `perldata` (run `perldoc perldata` and search 'Slices').

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! I now have learnt some more useful hints. With perl it's always like this: you know WHAT you want, it's just you don't know how to google for it. Search isn't much use when there are $'s and [s in queary string.

Comment: @perlerist It is called (array) slices, you can learn more about it from `perldata`.

Answer (score 5):

How about,

```
print @array[qw/1 5 7/] ;
```

In perl, there are ten ways to do anything.

Comment: I didn't know that there could be anything in the square brackets apart from simple 1+1. Awsome!